# How to keep the certbot container running?

Tags: docker-compose, certbot

I'm using the `certbot/certbot` container as in:

```
docker-compose run -d --rm --entrypoint 'certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot --staging --email example@domain.se -d example.com --rsa-key-size 4096 --agree-tos --force-renewal ; sleep 3600' certbot
```

on the following compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/nginx:/var/www/nginx"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/var/log/nginx"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/var/log/letsencrypt"
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

But it ignores the sleep command and the container goes away.

Whereas running the following:

```
docker-compose run -d --rm --entrypoint 'sleep 3600' certbot
```

keeps the container up and running.

I would like to keep the container up and running after the `certbot` failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move `"/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"` into dedicated script for example start.sh.

Mount it with docker-compose volumes

```
 volumes:
   - "./start.sh:/start.sh
 entrypoint: /start.sh
```

Comment: Yes of course, but I'm not building any image here.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You can mount it with volumes. I have just fixed the answer.